# CKFinder 3.4.2 for ASP.NET throws MissingMethodException for ImageProcessor.Imaging.ResizeLayer

Tags: ckfinder, imageprocessor

I am on .NET 4.7.2.

This is the specific exception I am getting:

```
Fatal | CKSource.CKFinder.Connector.Core.CommandHandler | 2020-06-23 09:53:46.6549 | An unknown error has occured during execution of FileUpload command.| System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void ImageProcessor.Imaging.ResizeLayer..ctor(System.Drawing.Size, ImageProcessor.Imaging.ResizeMode, ImageProcessor.Imaging.AnchorPosition, Boolean, Single[], System.Nullable`1<System.Drawing.Size>, System.Collections.Generic.List`1<System.Drawing.Size>)'.
   at CKSource.CKFinder.Connector.Core.Commands.FileUpload.FileUploadCommandExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at CKSource.CKFinder.Connector.Core.Commands.FileUpload.FileUploadCommandExecutor.ExecuteAsync(FileUploadParameters commandParameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at CKSource.CKFinder.Connector.Core.Commands.FileUpload.FileUploadCommandImpl.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at CKSource.CKFinder.Connector.Core.CommandHandler.<ExecuteAsync>d__12.MoveNext()    at CKSource.CKFinder.Connector.Core.Commands.FileUpload.FileUploadCommandExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at CKSource.CKFinder.Connector.Core.Commands.FileUpload.FileUploadCommandExecutor.ExecuteAsync(FileUploadParameters commandParameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at CKSource.CKFinder.Connector.Core.Commands.FileUpload.FileUploadCommandImpl.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at CKSource.CKFinder.Connector.Core.CommandHandler.<ExecuteAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
```

I have tried all versions of ImageProcessor from 2.6.1.19 and up. The constructor does not take a Single[] like the exception says but a Float[].

Comment: That'll be a version mismatch. I'd compare the version CKFinder requires vs the one you have installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CKFinder.Connector.Core 3.4.2 is 3 years old and uses ImageProcessor 2.3.3

https://www.nuget.org/packages/CKSource.CKFinder.Connector.Core/3.4.2

Comment: This is it. I was looking at the most recent dependencies in nuget, not the dependencies for the version I had referenced.